# Routes configuration with 3 routers and 1 LAN

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, internet, routing

I have a problem with routes in ubuntu server.

I have 3 routers from 3 ISP.

Router-1 192.168.1.1 (Default gateway)
Router-2 192.168.1.2 (gateway for traffic of xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx server)
Router-3 192.168.1.3 (gateway for traffic of yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy server)

I want to route traffic to the server xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx by the router-2 192.168.1.2

And traffic to the server yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy by the router-3 192.168.1.3

but all traffic goes through the router 192.168.1.1 and not because

I explain:

- I have a network with 36 computers, all connect to internet by the Router-1 and configured with ip range type 192.168.1.1XX
- The network has 3 routers adsl (The 3 lines are 12 Mb for download and 2 for upload).
- Router-1 192.168.1.1
- Router-2 192.168.1.2
- Router-3 192.168.1.3
- I have an asterisk server (ubuntu lts 14.04) with a static IP configuration in the `/etc/network/interfaces`. This is the config:

  ```
  auto eth0
  iface eth0 inet static
  address 192.168.1.4
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  network 192.168.1.0
  broadcast 192.168.1.255
  gateway 192.168.1.1
  ```

Route for traffic of xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx server by router-2

```
post-up route add -net XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.1.2
pre-down route del -net XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.1.2
```

Route for traffic of yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy server by router-3

```
post-up route add -net yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.1.3
pre-down route del -net yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.1.3
```

I understand that I am wrong setting routes, not where.

Thanks in advance and kind regards

Comment: How about asking that on http://serverfault.com? They are more specialized in networking.

Comment: Edit your post and add the result of `netstat -rn` need to see what your routing table looks like

Comment: The table is empty

Comment: Huh impossible should at least have a default route. Or non of your connections would work. `sudo netstat -rn` ??

Comment: And show `ifquery -l` and `ifquery eth0`

Comment: `netstat -rn
Tabla de rutas IP del núcleo
Destino         Pasarela        Genmask         Indic   MSS Ventana irtt Interfaz
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0`

Comment: ´ifquery -l 
lo
eth0´

`ifquery eth0
address: 192.168.1.4
netmask: 255.255.255.0
broadcast: 192.168.1.255
network: 192.168.1.0
gateway: 192.168.1.1
up: route add -net 46.105.15.233 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.1.2
up: route add -net 5.196.15.8 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.1.3`

Comment: Hmm  try `ifup -nv --force eth0` and try manually adding `route add -net 46.105.15.233 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.1.2` then `netstat rn` to confirm that it accepted manual entry